# gpu::BFMatcher_GPU and BFMatcher gives Different Result

Tags: gpu, brute-force, surf

I am using OpenCv 2.4.10 with Cuda 7.0 on VS10

In my CPU project,  finding keypoints and matching like this;

```
detector = new cv::SURF(150,3);
descriptorExtractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");

detector->detect(gry0,keypoints0);
descriptorExtractor->compute(gry0, keypoints0, descriptor0); 

detector->detect(gry1,keypoints1);
descriptorExtractor->compute(gry1, keypoints1, descriptor1); 

cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_L2); 

matcher.match(descriptor1, descriptor0, matches);
```

In GPU;

```
cv::gpu::SURF_GPU surf(150,3);

surf(gpumatFrameGray0, cv::gpu::GpuMat(), keypoints0GPU, descriptors0GPU);
surf(gpumatFrameGray0, cv::gpu::GpuMat(), keypoints1GPU, descriptors1GPU);

surf.downloadKeypoints(keypoints0GPU,keypoints0);
surf.downloadKeypoints(keypoints0GPU,keypoints1);

cv::gpu::BFMatcher_GPU matcher(cv::NORM_L2);

matcher.matchSingle(descriptors1GPU, descriptors0GPU, trainIdx, distance);

matcher.matchDownload(trainIdx, distance, matches);
```

I have 2 questions.

1) Most of the location of Keypoints for CPU and GPU are same. There is a difference like 0,000002 between some values. Is this normal and why this happens?

2) My second and important question is that matching of CPU and GPU is different. I show a table of matching

[image: Matching Table]

This table shows position of keypoints in images that are matched for CPU and GPU.

For example a keypoint that has x position "22.333189" in Frame 0 matches two keypoints in frame 1 for CPU code.

But for GPU code, it matches to three different keypoints.

There are many differences like this. Because of this differences, result of homography also differs and algorithm gives different result. What is the solution of this problem?

Thank You

Comment: Few years ago I've got different results for `StereoBM` and some of cascade detection algorithm (as long as I remember).

Comment: Also I want to add something. Not only there is a difference between result of BruteForceMatcher for CPU and GPU, but also there is a difference between resuts of two different runtime of GPU for same input. On the other hand, a situation like this wasn't observed for CPU code.

Answer (score 3):

Like said in http://answers.opencv.org/question/10745/bfmatcher-implemented-differently-on-gpu/

Floating point arithmetics are slightly different on CPU and GPU, and furthermore, they can differ on same hardware using different libraries (like IPP or NPP).

Last but not least, GPU's SURF descriptors differ from CPU's.  So, matches will differ too.